# How to fetch specific data using regular expression in postgres sql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to fetch the values of a column if it contains special characters other than alphanumeric.

Ex: `select name from data;`

```
name

ACD12
A12DD
A_C12
A@CD
AB_M1
123AB
```

I need to write a regular expression to fetch the following data from the above table:

```
A_C12
A@CD
AB_M1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an expression that says "Any string that contains at least one non-alpha-numeric character":

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name ~ '[^[:alnum:]]'
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2edd5/15

I haven't used `\W` because it's equivalent to `[^[:alnum:]_]` and you don't want the underscore. See [the PostgreSQL docs on regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html).